# I want to get a tip of rm command filter by using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, rm

Some weeks ago, a senior team member removed an important oracle database file(.dbf) unexpectedly. Fortunately, We could restore the system by using back-up files which was saved some days ago.

After seeing that situation, I decided to implement a solution to make atleast a double confirmation when typing `rm` command on the prompt. (checks more than `rm -i`)

Even though we aliasing `rm -i` as default, super speedy keyboardists usually make mistakes like that member, including me.

At first, I replaced(by using alias) basic rm command to a specific bash script file which  prints and confirms many times if the targets are related on the oracle database paths or files.
simply speaking, the script operates as filter before to operate rm. If it is not related with oracle, then rm will operate as normal.

While implementing, I thought most of features are well operated as I expected only user prompt environment except one concern.

If rm command are called within other scripts(provided oracle, other vendor modifying oracle path, installer, etc) or programs(by using system call).

1. How can i distinguish that situation?
   If above provided scripts met modified rm, That execution doesn't go ahead anymore.
2. Do you have more sophisticated methods?

I believe most of reader can understand my lazy explanation.
If you couldn't get clear scenery from above, let me know. I will elaborate more.

Answer (score 3):

We read at `man bash`:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the
>   expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt.

Then if you use `alias` to make `rm` invoke your shell script, other scripts won't use it by default. If it's what you want, then you're already safe.

The problem is if you *want* your version of rm to be invoked by scripts and do something smart when it happens. Alias is not enough for the former; even putting your `rm` somewhere under `$PATH` is not enough for programs explicitly calling `/bin/rm`. And for programs that aren't shell scripts, `unlink` system call is much more likely to be used than something like `system("rm ...")`.

I think that for the whole "safe rm" thing to be useful, it should avoid prompts even when invoked interactively. Every user will develop the habit of saying "yes" to it, and there is no known way around that. What might work is something that moves files to recycle bin instead of deletion, making damage easy to undo (as I seem to recall, there were ready to use solutions for this).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is into the `alias` manpage:

```
          Note  aliases  are  not  expanded  by default in non-interactive
          shell, and it can be enabled by setting the expand_aliases shell
          option using shopt.
```

Check it by yourself with `man alias` ;)

Anyway, i would do it in the same way you've chosen

Answer (score 0):

To distinguish the situation:  You can create an env variable say, `APPL`, which will be set to say `export APPL="DATABASE` . In your customized `rm` script, perform the double checkings only if the `APPL` is `DATABASE` (which indicates a database related script), not otherwise which means the `rm` call is from other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `bash`, you can **export** your shell function, which will make it available in scripts, too.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Define a replacement for `rm` and export it. 
rm() { echo "PSYCH."; }; export -f rm
```

Shell functions take precedence over builtins and external utilities, so by using just `rm` even scripts will invoke the function - unless they explicitly bypass the function by invoking `/bin/rm ...` or `command rm ...`.

Place the above (with your actual implementation of `rm()`) either in each user's `~/.bashrc` file, or in the system-wide bash profile - sadly, its location is not standardized (e.g.: Ubuntu: `/etc/bash.bashrc`; Fedora `/etc/bashrc`)